# PHP access sub array list gone wrong result and length

Tags: php, arrays

I have an PHP Array with Object with below sample:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [menuID] => 1
        [menuName] => AA
        [menuURL] => 
        [subMenu] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [subMenuID] => 1
                        [subMenuName] => Sub 1
                        [subMenuURL] => ab
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [subMenuID] => 2
                        [subMenuName] => Sub 2
                        [subMenuURL] => ac
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [menuID] => 2
        [menuName] => AB
        [menuURL] => 
        [subMenu] => 
    )

)
```

Now I need to count and access array in `subMenu` but got strange value there.

I'm using this code:

```
foreach ($headerMenu as $list) {
    //print_r($list['menuName']);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(count($list['subMenu']));
}
```

It show me result `2` and `1`. As you can see on the above sample array, it should show `2` for menu ID 1 and `0` for menu ID 2.

Is there any way how to solve it?

Comment: Can you maybe share a sample code which is reproducable? Maybe an example array 
 written in php? Because writing your given example in php works as expected (Altough your second array "subMenu" is null which should produce a php error since null is not countable). Make sure you have the correct example attached.

Comment: subMenu for second array should be an empty array ( [subMenu] =>[] )for your desired answer. Your current code should throw error for count() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the error, but I just changed the syntax, and tried it in Wamp, and it did print 2 and 0.

```
<?php
$headerMenu = array(
    array(
        'menuID' => 1,
        'menuName' => 'AA',
        'menuURL' => '',
        'subMenu' => array(
            array(
                'subMenuID' => 1,
                'subMenuName' => 'Sub 1',
                'subMenuURL' => 'ab'
            ),
            array(
                'subMenuID' => 2,
                'subMenuName' => 'Sub 2',
                'subMenuURL' => 'ac'
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        'menuID' => 2,
        'menuName' => 'AB',
        'menuURL' => '',
        'subMenu' => array()
    )
);

foreach ($headerMenu as $list) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(count($list['subMenu']));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

better to use the `is_array()` and check if `subMenu` is an array or not before counting it!

```
foreach ($headerMenu as $list) {
    //print_r($list['menuName']);

    echo "<pre>";
    if (is_array($list['subMenu'])) {
        print_r(count($list['subMenu']));
    } else {
        print_r(0);
    }
}
```